# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS , Doesn't redirect to the login page

Tags: php, .htaccess, phpbb3

I have a phpBB3 forum and I have a issue with my redirect from HTTP to HTTPS.

I am using in my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Now everything works perfect besides the Login page , when I press on Login it redirects me to https://www.crowned.ro/ucp.php?mode=login , but my forum is located in /forum and for some reasons only the login doesn't want to redirect properly.

In this image you can see that if you hover over the Login button in the corner it shows the good link . http://prntscr.com/dojio3

Comment: Which version of phpbb are you using ?

Comment: @AlexandreT I've solved the problem , on img src="" I used HTTP:// instead of HTTPS:// for background and that's why it keep blocking it .

Comment: If you solved it, please write the answer to your own question and check it as resolved. So, contributors don't loose time by reading a solved question. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this happens to you too , check if the images has HTTP:// if they do change with HTTPS:// , because SSL requires every connection to be HTTPS:// in order to show up everything properly.